# Pi UART receiving extra bytes

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

As part of a bigger project I am trying to setup the UART on two Raspberry Pi Zero Ws to talk to one another.

At the moment I just want to send and receive something simple to prove the UARTs work. However, I appear to be receiving some bytes that I am not intentionally sending.

On the transmit side my code is really simple and looks like this

```
    import serial
    from time import sleep
    port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)
    while True:
        port.write(bytes.fromhex('deadbeef')
        sleep(5)
```

On the receive side it's equally as simple and looks like this

```
    import serial
    from time import sleep
    port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)
    while True:
        received = port.read(8)
        print(received)
```

The output in the shell looks like this...

```
b''
b'\xde\xad\be\xef'
b'\xde\xad\be\xef'
b''
b'\xde\xad\be\xef'
b''
b'\xde\xad\be\xef'
b'\xde\xad\be\xef'
b''
b'\xde\xad\be\xef'
```

Basically I am getting that extra `b''` and I can't work out why!!!

Have I missed something really obvious? Could this be something else communicating on the UART? Can anyone help explain this?

Thank you for any help you can offer.

Comment: Did you set your parity and stop bits?

Comment: You are writing something once every 5 seconds, but reading with a timeout of 3 seconds - so it's going to time out and return an empty string about half the time.  Also note that you're writing 4 bytes at a time, but calling `.read(8)`, so even the successful reads are returning due to a timeout.

Comment: @jurez I haven't specifically set parity and stop bits, i'll add that now

Comment: @jasonharper Ahh, thank you. Changing the timeout does fix the problem. And i've corrected the writing 4 bytes receiving 8. Thank you for your help